# Check T is one-one ??

Tags: linear-transformations

A linear transfomation T:$\mathbb{P}_{3}\rightarrow\mathbb{P}_{3}$such
that T{[}p(x){]}=p''(x) +p(x).Check

1. T is one-one?

2.T is onto?

MY APPROACH: Ker(T) is given by p''(x)+p(x)=0 a differential eqn whose
solution is p(x)=Acosx +Bsinx.I think p(x) is periodic function hence
Ker(T) is not Trivial.So T is neither one one  nor onto.

ANOTHER APPROACH : T(1),T(x),T(x$^{2}$ ),T(x$^{3})$are Linearly
independent vectors belonging to Range(T).Hence Ker(T) is trivial.Hence
T is one one and onto.

Comment: But is your $p(x)$ in the domain of $T$?

Comment: The second approach is correct. The first one makes no sense as trigonometric functions are not in $P$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first approach without differential equations: let $p \in ker(T)$.

Then $p''+p=0$. Hence $p^{(4)}+p''=0$. Since $p^{(4)}=0$, we get $p''=0$ and therefore $p=0$.